# Show that $1<|G:\ker\psi|$ and that the index $|G:\ker\psi|$ divides the order $|G'|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $\psi:G\rightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism such that $\psi(G)\neq\lbrace 1\rbrace$. Suppose that the orders of $|G|=18$ and $|G'|=15$.

Show that $1<|G:\ker\psi|$ and that the index $|G:\ker\psi|$ divides the order $|G'|$. What is the order $|\ker\psi|$?

I came across this question in a practice quiz and have no idea how to provide a proof for this. In the textbooks I've been using, I haven't come across something like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the first point, think of the First Homomorphism Theorem.

Comment: BTW, you didn't rule out the trivial homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

**Hints:**

1. What does $\psi(G) \neq \{1\}$ tell you about $\ker(\psi)$?
2. What do you know about $|G : \ker(\psi)|$? (Try using the first isomorphism theorem.)
3. Can you determine $|G : \ker(\psi)|$ now? Can you use it to determine $|\ker(\psi)|$?

Answer (score 0):

By the first isomorphism theorem, $G/\operatorname{ker}\psi\cong\psi(G)$.  By Lagrange's theorem, $|\psi(G)|||G'|=15$.  But of course, $[G:\operatorname{ker}\psi]||G|=18$.

Thus, $[G:\operatorname{ker}\psi]=3\implies|\operatorname{ker}\psi|=6$.